# how to cast System.String to System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, casting, type-conversion

I'm new to the asp.net, I want to cast System.String to System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox in asp.net?

I'm developing one shopping web site. In that i'm having some checkbox controls. And I want t0o maintain the checked state of each checkbox control on my web page. For that i created one datatable dynamically & when user check particular checkbox control that time i'm storing name of the checkbox in the datatable as a string datatype. And depending on the checkbox name i want to check particular check box control on particular page of my web site. so that's why i need above conversion.

Is there any another solution on this situation?

thanks.

Comment: i dont think  its possible . where  u need this type of conversion

Comment: Explain more clearly what you are hoping to accomplish.  What you are proposing is grossly incorrect

Comment: You can't cast -- the types are not related. Perhaps create a CheckBox and then assign a value to it based upon the contents of the String? (Read: explain what is *really* desired?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cast `string` to `System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox` as they are not compatible types.

You need to get the checkbox name from the database and find it on your page.

Assuming that you read from the database the name "chkProduct" you need to do something like the following, for example:

```
(this.FindControl("chkProduct") as CheckBox).Checked=true;
```

Of course above code is not safe. You should check for NULLs, etc. Perhaps your control is nested inside another container, in that case you need to find it recursively.

But in reality, you shouldn't need to "Find" anything since your checkbox controls are likely to be defined in your markup (unless you bind them dynamically). If they are defined in the markup, you could simply have an if/else statement:

```
if(name=="chkProduct")
  chkProduct.Checked=true;
if(name=="chkColorRed")
 chkColorRed.Checked=true;
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

bind your checkbox with data items

Comment: I don't have any table. And my checkbox control is unbound control.

Comment: You said : " i created one datatable dynamically & when user check particular checkbox control that time i'm storing name of the checkbox in the datatable as a string datatype"

Comment: That's what i'm trying to say that after clicking checkbox i'm only inserting name of the checkbox in my datatable. And i think your misunderstanding  me that my checkbox is initially bound to my datatable that's what you are considering.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `checkbox list` and you can use the Item.value to store in your datatable as it wil be easy to maintain .

i used this

```
foreach (ListItem li in chbCategory.Items)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                if (li.Selected == true)
                {
                    dr["Id"] = li.Value;
                    dr["Status"] = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["Id"] = li.Value;
                    dr["Status"] = 0;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
```

for storing the selected items in `datatable`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using following method-

```
Dim chkname as string = dt.Rows(0).Item("ChkBoxName")
Dim chk As CheckBox = CType(Page.FindControl(chkname), CheckBox)
chk.Checked = True
```